# Rails 3 authorization with default auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, authorization

I working on an app with user authorization. It has a `List` and `User` classes. The authentication was built with Ryan Bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

I'm not sure about authorization process. I read about `cancan` gem. But i could not understand.

I want to achieve this:

1. User only able to view/edit/delete his own list.
2. User only able to view/edit/delete his own profile(user class).

I don't implement user level right now. No guess or admin.

How to use before_filter method in `list` and `User` controller with `current_user` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are defining `current_user` in the application controller, this is easy. You can use `before_filter` like this in the Users controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_if_owner, :only => [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  def check_if_owner
    unless current_user.admin? # check whether the user is admin, preferably by a method in the model
      unless # check whether the current user is the owner of the item (or whether it is his account) like 'current_user.id == params[:id].to_i'
        flash[:notice] = "You dont have permission to modify this item"
        redirect_to # some path
        return
      end
    end
  end

  ###

end
```

You should add a similar method to UsersController to check if it is his profile, he is editing.

Also, have a look at [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which is the recommended plugin for authentication purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For this I'd not use devise. It's way to much for this simple use.

I'd make a seperate controller for the public views and always refere to current_user 
Remember to make routes for the actions in the PublicController

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :login_required?
 def list
  @list = current_user.list
 end
 def user
  @user = current_user
 end
 def user_delete
  @user = current_user
   # do your magic
 end
 def user_update
  @user = current_user
   # do your magic
 end

# and so on...
end
```